# Better way to change class?

Tags: c++

I have a program that reads some bytes from a file. If the second byte is exactly 0, it should cast the current type to the correct one.

This is what I have:

```
struct Event {
    virtual ~Event() {}
};

struct MidiEvent : public Event {
    unsigned m_channel;
    uint8_t byte1;
    uint8_t byte2;
    MidiEvent(uint8_t channel) : m_channel{ channel } {}
};

struct EventNoteOff : public MidiEvent {
    uint8_t note() { return byte1; }
    uint8_t velocity() { return byte2; }
    EventNoteOff(std::fstream& t_midi_file, uint8_t channel);
};

struct EventNoteOn : public MidiEvent {
    uint8_t note() { return byte1; }
    uint8_t velocity() { return byte2; }
    EventNoteOn(std::fstream& t_midi_file, uint8_t channel);
};
```

And this is the part where the program decides which class assign to each bytes:

```
// track_type and track_chanel is a "uint8_t", m_event is a "Event *" and t_midi_file is a std::fstream opened with 'in' and 'binary' flags.

switch (track_type) {
    case 0x80:
        m_event = new EventNoteOff{ t_midi_file, track_channel };
        break;
    case 0x90:
        t_midi_file.seekg(1, t_midi_file.cur);
        char c;
        t_midi_file.read(&c, 1);
        t_midi_file.seekg(-2, t_midi_file.cur);
        if (c == 0)
            m_event = new EventNoteOff{ t_midi_file, track_channel };
        else
            m_event = new EventNoteOn{ t_midi_file, track_channel };
        break;
    ...
}
```

Whenever `track_type` is 0x90 and `byte2` has the value of 0, i want `m_event` to behave like a `EventNoteOff*` with same values as before, not as an `EventNoteOn*`. My attempt works but I get a feel that this approach is dirty because it involves moving around the file read pointer and creating a temporal variable, when *I think* it could be done with a `reinterpret_cast`.

I tried doing

```
    case 0x90:
        m_event = new EventNoteOn{ t_midi_file, track_channel };
        if(dynamic_cast<EventNoteOn*>(m_event)->velocity() == 0)
            m_event = reinterpret_cast<EventNoteOff*>(m_event);
        break;
```

with no luck.

What is a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is for finding solutions to coding problems.  For advice on improving working code, please use [codereview.se] instead.

Comment: No, reinterpret_cast in this context is undefined behaviour.

Comment: `m_event` needs to be a `std::unique_ptr<MidiEvent>` (or `std::shared_ptr`), *not* `MidiEvent*`, otherwise you are going to have a huge memory leak.  You might be able to save re-reading the file all the time with a judicious bit of caching, but basically you have to have the information somewhere, and the only way to change what `m_event` is pointing at, is to, errm, change the object it is pointing to.

Comment: Your event hierarchy makes little sense. There is nothing that is common to all events, so their base class is empty. A class with no functionality has no reason to exist.

Comment: @n.m. Actually, this is a piece of code smaller than the actual code; I removed all the superfluous things to focus only in the structure.

Comment: OK then. Next, it is not very clear why you decide to create a note off event when the file format calls for a note on event with zero velocity. Why do you think this is appropriate? Not all instruments are grand piano.

Comment: @n.m. When being on running status, every note on event with zero velocity is treated as a note off event.

Comment: Hmm too complicated for me. Anyway. Seeking on a MIDI stream may or may not be a good idea. How do you seek on a live real-time wire signal? Not gonna work. OTOH reinterpret cast is clearly an UB. So neither of your solutions is ideal. I would have event constructors take a sequence of bytes that encode the event rather than the stream. Alternatively, create a note-on and then just check and replace it with a note-off if needed.